Why does my Dell inspiron 1545 do this!
My Ubuntu 24.04 Multiplys desktop folders like they are a part of the background. When i restart the system it reverses to normal. Help

Sounds like a "Ding" issue. Open your Extensions Manager and find Ding. Turn it off/disable it. If the duplicates disappear then it's configuration issue. Turn Ding back on.Fix #1 install dconf editor with: sudo apt-get install dconf-editor. Open dconf app from your apps menu and go to: org.gnome.desktop.background and change show-desktop-icons to false. That should fix it. You may need to restart you computer to see changes. Fix#2  Disable "Ding", open dconf and go to: org.gnome.desktop.background and change show-desktop-icons to true. You will need to restart you computer to see changes. Now right-click on the desktop and you'll see a menu. Choose "customize" and this will open the x-settings "Current Monitor Settings" (mine is Wayland). That is the menu for icons/mounted volumes. Hope this helps.

fixed by itself
